# How to pass a type to a method - Type argument vs generics

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, types, factory

I have a method of an object which is something like a factory. You give it a type, it creates an instance and does a few other things. An elegant way to do it (in my opinion) is like this:

```
public T MagicMethod<T>() where T: SomeBaseClass
{
    // Magic goes here
}
```

But this upsets FxCop who says that this is a bad style - I get a "CA1004: Generic methods should provide type parameter" warning. Something about not being to use inference and stuff. So, the only other way I can think of is something like this:

```
public SomeBaseClass MagicMethod(Type T)
{
    // Same magic goes here
}
```

I believe this is inferior to the first method on many accounts, but the style rule... The MSDN article on the warning even says that there is no reason for suppressing it.

Am I doing it right by suppressing this warning after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FXCop warnings are just that - warnings.  Just like implicit cast warnings, they serve to let you know that something you're doing may have behavior you're not anticipating, or may not be what you intended.

An implicit cast warning is dealt with by looking at the code, determinining if you really did intend to do that, and if so, adding an explicit cast.

Same thing with FXCop.  Look at the warning, look at your code, and determine if the warning is valid.  If it is, fix it.  If not, suppress it.  A suppression is the equivalent of an explicit cast - "Yes, FXCop, I'm sure I want to do this."

If it was really truly an error, it would probably be a compiler error.

Comment: Yes, but the MSDN page with the details on this warning explicitly states that "you should not suppress this warning". Honestly, am I smarter than the collective wisdom of the FXCop team?

Answer (score 19):

I believe you're misunderstanding what FxCop is telling you, probably because its wording is less than ideal. What it means is that *a generic method should provide a parameter that **is of that type***, not that a generic method should have a non-generic overload that provides a runtime `Type` instance. For example,

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T myParam);
```

The `myParam` is the sort of parameter it's referring to. The reason it wants this is, as you suggest, for inference. This allows you to do something like...

```
string foo = "bar";

DoSomething(foo);
```

instead of having to write

```
DoSomething<string>(foo);
```

In your case, it's fine to suppress the warning since you *want* the user to explicitly specify the type. I would suggest, however (assuming that your constructors are parameterless) that you change your `where` to `where T : SomeBaseClass, new()`. This means that it will direct the compiler to require that whatever type is passed in have a parameterless constructor. This also means that you can do `new T()` in your code.

Comment: Well... actually, it's not exactly a constructor... it calls into another 3rd party library where I give the type as a simple Type parameter, and that then constructs the object... But those are unnecessary details anyway. :)

Answer (score 5):

I would have no issue with suppressing this warning. For starters the equivalent in MS's own code is [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx)

```
public static T CreateInstance<T>()
```

It implies that the analysis rule should consider whether the *return type* of the method is covered by the generic parameter...

This has been mentioned in many places before:

- [CA1004 is not always appropriate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/6f5428e0-4095-40cb-ba40-b31e0cffc2fa)
- [FxCop Microsoft.Design and Generic outputs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/81f356fd-3821-47bd-ad30-c0a6b70aade5)

And there have been previous bugs in the rule for example:

```
public static void GenericMethod<T>(List<T> arg);
```

previously would trigger it ([fixed in 2005 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2006/10/13/visual-studio-2005-sp1-bug-fixes.aspx)).

I suggest filing a connect bug for your specific example

Comment: Phew. So it's not just me! :)

Answer (score 1):

FxCop will fire that warning even if you do use the generic type parameter in one or more of the arguments, if it is not "stripped":

```
public void LinkedList<T> Slice<T>(LinkedList<T> collection, Predicate<T> match)
{
    ...
}
```

At least rule 'CA1004' fired "in error" here the other day on a method with this signature.

For being smarter than the FxCop team, I'm not sure that the rules are able to correctly determine code in all cases, that's what the confidence level is for :)

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is not even equivalent to the first.  In the second one, you are literally given a type but you can't instantiate an object of that type (unless you use Reflection --- eeek!) and you have to explicitly declare the return type (which defeats the purpose of generics to begin with).

See [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=93247) note about suppressing it.  It looks like it is okay to suppress.

**EDIT:** Now here is another idea.  What if you changed it to an 'out' parameter and didn't return it through the return variable?  Would it remove the warning then?

```
public void MagicMethod<T>( out T retVar ) where T: SomeBaseClass
{
    // Magic goes here
}
```

Comment: Probably, but that wouldn't be very comfortable to use. :)

Comment: True, can't fault you at that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would bother with most warning in Fxcop.

You seem to know what you are doing, why would some automated piece of software know better?

Well, it cant, it's a guess.

Comment: Well, I figured that a lot more talented and experienced developers than me have written that tool, and if they say I shouldn't do it, maybe I shouldn't. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all that warning is just to make sure that callers do everything knowingly. It is possible to call your method without passing any type parameter because the compiler knows the type of the object before hand. FxCop is telling you to let it be implicit so that syntax for using generic and non-generic overloads looks identical (I disagree with that principle but that is personal and not relevant here).

Secondly, your second method will do more damage than you can think of right now. There is no compile time type checking there, so be warned of runtime invalid cast exceptions if you use it.